# Give the command to remove duplicate lines in a .txt file and save the new file as new.txt file

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line

I'm trying to do this but I cant create the file.

I enter: `sort myfile.txt uniq -u | tee newfile.txt`

and It wont create the file automatically. What am I missing here?

Comment: You should probably pick one of either 'sort' or 'uniq'. That should help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are missing one pipe `|` character.

Try: `sort myfile |uniq -u|tee newfile.txt`

If this is not working, please provide the error message you are getting.
By the way, this command `uniq -u` eliminates all lines which have duplicates. If this is your intention, that is fine. But if you want to see one of the duplicate lines, you need to drop `-u` for the `uniq` part of this command line, i.e., `sort myfile | uniq | tee newfile.txt`

Comment: worked just fine bro. I thought to add a pipe but UNIX makes you scared to second guess, second guessing yourself.

Comment: Thank you @MelBurslan for your comment about `uniq -u`